# How i can use script session outside script folder like home folder?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I use script on my website like this `localhost/panel/index.php`
in `index.php` the script set session like this

```
$cookie_lifetime = ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime') ? ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime') : 0;
session_set_cookie_params($cookie_lifetime , rtrim(dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]),"/") . "/", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $ssl, true);
session_start();
```

I need to use this session on `localhost/index.php` by using this session.

Comment: Why can't you delete that line? That line causes your problem.

Comment: You want to restrict the session ID cookie to only that specific path? What happens if you type `'/index.php'` as second parameter in `session_set_cookie_params()`?

Comment: yes this work, if i set second parameter is '/', but this is safe ?

Comment: Okay, please set is an answer to give you best answer, thanks.

Comment: @ObadaDiab Why wouldn't it be safe?

Comment: Idk, i am still noob in php, i was think it not safe because we change path not more, sorry for dummy question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the session cookie path to a fixed location you don't need any calculation:

```
session_set_cookie_params($cookie_lifetime , '/index.php', $ssl, true);
```

It's worth noting that the [default value](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path) is `/`.